# Unable show youtube embed video in Webview without "http/https"

Tags: android, webview, youtube

Currently I'm working on news reader android app, and show article in webview, I have some issues when displaying embedded video from youtube, my WYSIWYG generate code below

```
<iframe height="360" width="640" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/PS6JupCFnNM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but it cannot load in webview, then I found something to fixed this problem, with adding http/https in src url like

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PS6JupCFnNM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

the second format is original from youtube embed box that I copied from there, and it work, now what I supposed to do, is there a way to make webview show the youtube video with `src="//www.youtube.com/embed/PS6JupCFnNM"` format or I must modification my WYSIWYG instead?
thanks for your help. I hope my question does not duplicate with another webview question.

Comment: How are you loading your HTML into the `WebView`?

Comment: I just put into `webview.loadData(htmlCode, "text/html", "utf-8");` currently I'm using `str_replace` in my API to add `https` or `http` in src on iframe tags..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use base url.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://.", htmlCode, TEXT_HTML, "UTF-8", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, where the base URL that you provide has the `https` scheme.

Answer (score 0):

i was done by adding `utf-8` encoding.
like that:

```
webview.loadData(html,"text/html", "utf-8");
```